# Edit got through that should not have, reverted back

Tags: support, edits, approval

I have no clue which place to take this. Recently I answered a question and it was edited without my consent by someone with `100` something rep so it was not an auto edit. It was an edit that did not help my post in fact did harm to it.
[image]

In the picture I provided you see that while the editor fixed some spacing, they added `very` and `imo`. Also an unnecessary ```. Luckily @Adrian Mole fixed these bad edits. Yes it is resolved, but I don't get how @Aaquib Bashir's edit was approved.

Comment: Looks like Adrian Mole selected "improve edit" instead of "reject". Wouldn't like to speculate why.

Comment: You may be able to ping adrian with an @ comment. I figure he thought it would be easier than reject and edit. You should fix the *You'veovercomplicated* typo, though.

Comment: “Edit approved” link will provide all the insight you need; Now I don’t personally approve incomplete edit proposals for this reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As khelwood has stated in the comments, I reviewed that edit and 'approved' it by selecting "Improve Edit."

I agree that, as it stood, it was not ideal; however, the basic correction (adding the space before "overcomplicated") was fine, so I fixed the bad formatting that was introduced at the same time and removed the "imo" (which was superfluous).

The other option would have been to "Reject and Edit." But that would have, IMHO, sent the wrong message to the editor – whom I assume meant well.

The choice between "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit" is often a tricky one and nearly always subjective. Generally, I choose the option that will involve less typing on my part but, in this case, I felt that the correction 'justified' the +2 for the editor.

---

Note also, that in this particular case, *just* adding a space between "You've" and "overcomplicated" would not have been an option for the original editor: suggested edits need to make at least 6 (5?) characters' difference from the original post.

Comment: Given that it was not a good edit, wouldn't rejecting it have sent the right message? That message being "this is not a good edit"

Comment: @khelwood Hmm. Possibly. I guess I was in a charitable mood. But the basic correction *was* an improvement. The misplaced backticks were probably just an error and the bad effect of the addition of "imo" was cancelled by good effect of the correction, imo.

Comment: *"...suggested edits need to make at least 6 (5?) characters' difference from the original post."* They could have also fixed the grammar in the last sentence so it said "to accomplish" instead of "accomplishing". That said, these kinds of "they fixed at least one thing but messed at least one other thing up" edits are the most frustrating to review.

Comment: @BSMP I was just wondering when the "accomplishing" factor would come into play!

Comment: Or perhaps add the missing comma after Enumerate() for the introductory (participial? - I am not sure about the classification) phrase: *"Using Enumerate(), ..."* (6.35 in *The Chicago Manual of Style*)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yep! All-in-all, not my finest ever contribution to the Review Queues. However, I feel that my action did, at least, mitigate the main issue(s), and the OP *seems* to approve of what I did, even if not of the way in which I did it.